# How Spark casts data works when comparing different datatypes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I compare a `Int` with a `String`, Spark casts the right hand side

```
sql("SELECT 1621335543 >= '2021-05-18'").explain(true)

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(1621335543 >= CAST(2021-05-18 AS INT)): boolean
Project [(1621335543 >= cast(2021-05-18 as int)) AS (1621335543 >= CAST(2021-05-18 AS INT))#1309]
+- OneRowRelation
```

In this case, Spark casts the value `'2021-05-18'` to `Int` and the result is `NULL`.

But when I compare a `Timestamp` with a `String`, Spark casts the left hand side

```
sql("SELECT current_timestamp() >= '2021-05-18'").explain(true)

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(CAST(current_timestamp() AS STRING) >= 2021-05-18): boolean
Project [(cast(current_timestamp() as string) >= 2021-05-18) AS (CAST(current_timestamp() AS STRING) >= 2021-05-18)#1313]
+- OneRowRelation
```

How Spark chooses which DataType to cast ?

Answer (score 1):

This comment from spark code base is related to your question and following should be the expected behaviour in latest spark version:

> For equality between string and timestamp we cast the string to a
> timestamp so that things like rounding of subsecond precision does not
> affect the comparison.

Relevant reference to spark code is [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/TypeCoercion.scala#L1076). Which spark version are you using ?